# Set php_value for custom URL with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I want to set a PHP value just for some URL. For example, I have many URLs and one of them is `http://example.com/admin`. I want to add `post_max_size` `php_value` for this URL only.

Comment: Is `/admin` a physical directory?

Comment: @MrWhite No,it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use an Apache expression (Apache 2.4) in `.htaccess` to isolate that one URL, otherwise the directive will naturally apply to this directory tree.

Something like:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/admin'">
    php_value post_max_size 64M
</If>
```

Whether you can set a `php_value` at all in `.htaccess` is dependent on PHP being installed as an Apache module.

Comment: Using an Apache expression in this way is just a theory, I’ve not been able to test this myself. Presumably you don’t get an error? If you simply have the `php_value` directive on its own does it “work” (in that the `post_max_size` value is correctly set)? Presumably you are actually sending the POST request to this URL?

Comment: There is not an error with your method. I was used `echo` the value with `ini_get` and it was the `php.ini` value and not changed.No, I have tested it with `GET` method, but not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately the construct

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/admin'">
    php_value post_max_size 64M
</If>
```

doesn't work, because it seems, that on "php_value" parameter parse, the REQUEST_URI variable is not initalized. I managed to get it working by comparing THE_REQUEST variable and preg matching:

```
<If "'%{THE_REQUEST}' =~ m#uploadPublic.php#">
    php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
    php_value post_max_size 100M
</If>
```